# why do corona sdk's scene hide event not fired? and why timers are still printing stuff into the console even though i remove the scene?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

this is how I start the timers

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

timersArray = {}

function scene:create( event )

  function performTimedEvents(timeString)

  local function onTimer( event )
      local params = event.source.params
      if(arg == 5) then
        timer.cancel( event.source )
        return
      end
  end

  for i=1,10 do 
      --print("performWithDelay "..sliceStars(timeString)[i])
      timersArray[i] = timer.performWithDelay( 1000*sliceStars(timeString)[i], onTimer )
      timersArray[i].params = { n = i }
  end

  end

  performTimedEvents(pagesTimers[currentPage])
end
```

this is how I cancel the timers (before leaving the scene) but they are still there when I leave the scene, the timers are still printing stuff into the console... notice this specific line `timer.cancel(timersArray[j])`

```
function flushTimers()
  pageSequence(5)
  print("QQQtimersArray")
  print_r(timersArray)
  for j=1,#timersArray do
    print("didCancelTimer "..j)
    timer.cancel(timersArray[j])
    --timer.pause(timersArray[j])
    timersArray[j] = nil
  end
  timersArray = {}
  print_r(timersArray)
  print("didReturn");
end
```

also why scene:hide is not being fired, it used to work at old times when we had storyboard with exit, but this hide callback is not getting called, please help :(

```
function scene:hide( event )

print("YYY_hide_!!!")

local sceneGroup = self.view
local phase = event.phase



if ( phase == "will" ) then
    print("YYY_hide_will")
    -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)
    -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene
    -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
    print("YYY_hide_did")
    -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen
end
end

function scene:destroy( event )

local sceneGroup = self.view

-- Called prior to the removal of scene's view
-- Insert code here to clean up the scene
-- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.

--myAudioPlayer = nil
--audio.stop()
--audio.rewind(1)
flushTimers()
--timersArray = nil

print("YYY_destroy_did")
end


scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
```

by the way, this is how I remove the current scene

```
      composer.removeScene("currentScene")
      composer.gotoScene("nextScene",effectOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cancel your timers when the phase is did inside your scene:hide() event.

```
function scene:hide( event )

    print("YYY_hide_!!!")

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        print("YYY_hide_will")
        -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)
        -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene
        -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        print("YYY_hide_did")
        -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen
        flushTimers()
        composer.removeScene("sceneName")
    end
end
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but this event is not firing :(
'print("YYY_hide_!!!")' is not getting printed alltogether, I really need support with this problem, i wish I can start a bounty today, but i need two days to be able to do so.